# 'Response' object has no attribute 'get' in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, syntax-error

### AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get' in django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2klO.png)

Comment: Please don't use images. And give us a code snippet so we can see where is the problem.

Comment: Paste code instead of uploading images of code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: a request typically has methods like `get()` while a response typically has methods like `ok()` and `json()`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `get` with Response instead you should use the `request.get`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is coming from the middleware which processes your returned response from the view. Most certainly you return something from your view which is not a valid HTTP Response but of a type "Response"... as no code is provided it is difficult to say what "Response" actually is in your case.

here is a standard way to start with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
   response = HttpResponse("My response from view")
   return response
```

or a rendered template response:

```
   return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```